# XML to JSON conversion missing the element

Tags: java, json

I am newbie in JAVA programming and trying to convert XML to JAVA using the below snipet.

Input File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<ns0:MT_ECCJDBC xmlns:ns0="urn:xml:json">
-<REQUEST>
<ID>46565665</ID>
</REQUEST>
</ns0:MT_ECCJDBC>
```

The output :

```
{
  "@xmlns:ns0": "urn:xml:json",
  "REQUEST": ["46565665"]
}
```

The expected output in JSON is

```
{
   "REQUEST": 

{
   " ID " : ["46565665"]
}

}
```

Below is my java code :

```
public class ConversionXMLtoJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                    {
        InputStream is = ConversionXMLtoJSON.class.getResourceAsStream("instance.xml");
        String xml = IOUtils.toString(is);
        XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );
        System.out.println( json.toString(2) );
    }                   
}
}
```

Please suggest me to add in the code

1. To remove the tag "@xmlns:ns0": "urn:xml:json",
2. To add the ID element in the JAVA code.

Regards

Comment: Is the format of the XML fixed? If so I will submit you an answer.

Comment: @Robin have a look [here](http://heshans.blogspot.in/2014/01/java-library-to-convert-xml-to-json.html) and [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/converting-json-to-xml-to-java-objects-using-xstream.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the XML into Java objects and then use JSON generator to generate the JSON. I like to use jackson-mapper-asl, jackson-core-asl and jackson-dataformat-xml.

To bind the XML to Java:

```
public class XmlRequest {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="REQUEST")
    private REQUEST request;


    public static class REQUEST {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ID")
        protected int ID;

        public int getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public void setID(int iD) {
            ID = iD;
        }

    }

    public REQUEST getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(REQUEST request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

To Generate the JSON:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
XmlRequest request = (XmlRequest) mapper.readValue(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/NewFile.xml"), XmlRequest.class);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

JsonGenerator jsongen = new JsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(System.out);

jsongen.writeStartObject();
jsongen.writeFieldName("REQUEST");
jsongen.writeStartObject();     
jsongen.writeFieldName("ID");
jsongen.writeStartArray();
jsongen.writeNumber(request.getRequest().getID());
jsongen.writeEndArray();
jsongen.writeEndObject();
jsongen.writeEndObject();
jsongen.close();
```

Comment: Dear Filip,Thanks for the response. I am trying to implement your program. Searching for all the packages required for that till I execute.

Comment: You need packages jackson-mapper-asl, jackson-core-asl and jackson-dataformat-xm